# Series Hidden when Dynamically Updating Series Type from Column to Line [Highcharts 3.0]

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/jriggs/8Sg8K/17/

See it by hitting the update button.

Ideally, I would just like for the line series to appear on top of the column, like adjusting the z-index, if that makes sense.

I've tried disable animations with no luck. Seems to have something to do with the order that the series are declared - but not sure.

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5]
        },{
            name: 'Cleveland',
            data: [10, 4, 11, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5]
        }]
    },

    function (chart) {
        $('#btn').click(function () {

            chart.series[0].update({
                type: "column"
            });

        });
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust the `zIndex` for each of the series just like you said:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5],
            zIndex: 10
        },{
            name: 'Cleveland',
            data: [10, 4, 11, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5],
            zIndex: 20
        }]
```

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/8Sg8K/18/).

Comment: I wont which series will be changed to line until runtime. Do you know if there is a way to explicitly state that the line series will always appear on top?

Comment: AFAIK no. But I imagine you could increment the `zIndex` of the series that the user (I assume) will choose and decrement the others as needed. Or iterate your loaded series and ensure that the `zIndex` of the line one(s) is/are greater than the others.

Comment: Or you can define index for column series, and for line series, and when setting type to column series using `update()` set also new zIndex. The same when coming back from column type to spline, see: http://jsfiddle.net/8Sg8K/19/